# Service context onCreate method gets initialized but then appears not initialized on method for storage of sqlite Data

Tags: android, service, null

I am implementing a foreground service, which runs in the background and its purpose is to store sensor data periodically on a SQLite Database. However i am having issues on the initialization of the SQlHelperClass, as the context appears to be null when the relevant method for the data storage executes.

First, i am initializing the context on the oncreate() method of the Service:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    context = applicationContext
}
```

Here, i can chech on the debugger that te context indeed has been initialized.

For some period the sensor send their values, and i have several arraylists which hold their values. When the method to store the data on the SQLite database executes however, the context appears to have not been initialized:

```
fun storeAllDataToSQlDatabase()
{

    //database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(database_path, null , SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
    sensorDBHandler = DBHandler(context)
    sensorDBHandler.writableDatabase
```

Why is this happening? I am not having another context statement during the app execution , so the value should not change by itself, correct?

Any help is appreciated.
Lampros

Edit 1:

What i figured out , from the debugging of the app, is that after the onCreate is called, the service variables are initialized again for some reason:

The program execution passes from this part again:
lateinit var  context : Context

So the program puts a null value to the already initialized context.

Why does this occur?

Edit 2:

This is how i start the service from the mainActivity:

```
//start a new intent for our foregraound service
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        var service = Intent(applicationContext, BoundSensorDataService::class.java)
        applicationContext?.startForegroundService(service)
    } else {
        var service = Intent(applicationContext, BoundSensorDataService::class.java)
        applicationContext?.startService(service)
    }
    applicationContext?.startForegroundService(intent)
}

BoundSensorDataService()!!.setUpSensorsAndListeners(sensorManager)
```

And here is how i stop the service:

```
  var intent = Intent(this , BoundSensorDataService::class.java)
  applicationContext.stopService(intent)
```

The  fun storeAllDataToSQlDatabase(sensorData : Data?) is called on the Service class, when 60 values have been stored on the relevant ArrayLists.

Comment: "the context appears to have not been initialized" -- how have you determined this? If it is because you are crashing, you might consider adding the complete stack trace to your [mcve]. Also, what is triggering the call to this `storeAllDataToSQlDatabase()`, and on what class is the `storeAllDataToSQlDatabase()` method located? What is starting and stopping your service?

Comment: This is how i start the service from the mainActivity: